# Simple mysql counts and time taken

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Ok so I have a local Ubuntu server in my house running Mysql. It has older style hard disks and I have a Linode running SSDs.

On the Linode a simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` counting 106938412 records takes 37.14 seconds whilst on my home box counting 5376224 records takes 39 minutes!! Clearly something is different. Where should I be looking to speed this up. If I were to move the non SSD data locally to a USB based drive would that speed it up? Currently I am running queries on both tables (lots of selects/inserts) so the tables would be "active" and both query sets would be updating indexes too so I'm not sure if that would account for the differences?

When I run `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM slow_table` shows `Select tables optimized away` so I don't believe this helps?

RAM and CPU on the local box are also fine.

Comment: Which [storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html) are you using? Anyway, you may get better help on the [dba.se] site where the DB experts are.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, instead of using `*`, use any specific column name, mostly a primary key column.

Try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Unfortunately not seeing any improvements